# Unable to read applicationContext.xml when executing the spring class as a runnable jar

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring class with main method. Inside the class am trying to read the values applicationContext.xml . My intention is to jar this main class along with its dependant jars,property files and applicationContext.xml .

But when i try to run the jar file via unix command prompt, it looks like the applicationContext file is not getting loaded.

The applicationContext.xml is seen inside the jar file and am able to see the sysouts inside my class.The code used to read the applicationContext.xml is

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "classpath*:**/applicationContext.xml");
```

When i print context it is giving me the below message.

```
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@89fbe3: start
up date [Mon Oct 01 15:07:43 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
```

When i try to print context.getBeanDefinitionCount() -- it gives me 0.

But am able to successfully excute this via eclipse . It is able able to read the applicationContext.xml and giving me the bean count as 13.

Not sure why it is not working when i run it as a jar.Please help me with your comments.

Comment: A jar file is just a zip file.  Try unzipping it and looking in.  Is the application context there?  Does it contain the content you expected?

Comment: Yes i unzippped and am able to see the applicationContext inside.But still it is not picking up the values.

Comment: Is there only one applicationContext.xml in the jar?  Are you sure there are no other jars on the classpath that might also contain an applicationContext.jar?

Comment: Did you ever get around this. I have also ran into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

How did you get the .jar package? Did you use Eclipse export wizard? It's likely that you have put the "applicationContext.xml" in "/resources" folder. Make sure you fix the "Java Build Path" in Eclipse. Remove all the exclude tags that may be present on "/src/main/resources" folder. The resource folder should be considered a classpath, not just a folder with some xml files in the .jar package. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quote from the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff) (emphasis mine):

> Please note that "classpath*:" when combined with Ant-style patterns will only work reliably with **at least one root directory before the pattern starts**, unless the actual target files reside in the file system. This means that a pattern like "classpath*:*.xml" will not retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the root of expanded directories. This originates from a limitation in the JDK's ClassLoader.getResources() method which only returns file system locations for a passed-in empty string (indicating potential roots to search).

Answer (score -1):

I have struggled with the same issue.  I can run my application fine from inside Eclipse, but when I export it as an executable jar, it fails.

I have worked around the issue by:

1. going to the build path screen in Eclipse and removing the filters on the `/resources` folder.  This causes the export to put the `META-INF` folder  and its contents that are under `/resources` into the top level of the `.jar` file.
2. Remove all the wildcards from the application context path:

   `applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                      "classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml");`
   becomes
    `applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");`

I am sure this is due to some difference in the classloader between the Eclipse environment and my windows java environment.  Figuring out how to resolve that will be the next task.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @JigarParekh The user only mentioned that they had the same issue as context for how they solved it. This is an answer, not a question.