# Unable to read log4j2.xml and applicationContext.xml when running as a runnable JAR

Tags: java, executable-jar

When I am running the application as a standalone JAR file it's throwing `FileNotFoundException`. It's not able to find `applicationContext.xml` under `/resources` — which is included in the JAR. It couldn't even find `log4j2.xml`, so it's using the default configuration.

Same question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671294/unable-to-read-applicationcontext-xml-when-executing-the-spring-class-as-a-runna), but I couldn't find any solution.

After some research and from the answers referred from the above link when I am exporting the project as JAR it's keeping config files under `/resources` folder inside the JAR; but it has to store under root directory `META-INF/`.

I unable to make it store it in root directory. When I am exporting automatically eclipse creating JAR with config files under `/resource` folder.

Comment: I think you might need to give more "context" about this one: Spring version (and "stack"), application structure, etc...otherwise it would be difficult for someone to figure things out without narrowing it

Answer (score 0):

The jar created by exporting from eclipse has config files under resource folder which won't work.

Resolved the problem after using jar created by maven build. This jar has its contents in proper structure and has config files under root directory.

Make sure to include the maven-jar plugins to include dependencies in manifest file.